# Select a table column from IEnumerable using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

Am having my table as below , by the usage of Sqlite :

```
public class Medication
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string unique_id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string insulin_type { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }

    public string alarm_time { get; set; }
    public Medication() { }
}
```

Now I want to use `IEnumerable` to get a Column `alarm_time` List but I don't know how to get it. Below is my code for that:

```
public IEnumerable<Medication> AllMedicationResults()
{
    return (from t in _connection.Table<Medication>()
            select t).ToList();
}
```

How can I include the Column `alarm_time` in that code above.

Comment: do you want only the `alarm_time` column?

Comment: yes @GiladGreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `select` request only that property (and change method return type)

```
public IEnumerable<string> AllMedicationResults()
{
    return (from t in _connection.Table<Medication>()
            select t.alarm_time).ToList();
}
```

But IMO it will look cleaner to just use method syntax:

```
public IEnumerable<string> AllMedicationResults()
{
    return  _connection.Table<Medication>().Select(t => t.alarm_time).ToList();
}
```

*Notice that as you are returning an `IEnumerable<T>` you might want to consider removing the `ToList()` and using the benefits of linq's deffered execution*

Comment: Thanks so much @Gilad

Comment: Am ticking you in 8 minutes

Comment: so you if i remove `ToList()` , i will be returning a pure IEnumerable items, meaning that if i put `ToList()` , they will be converting it to List?

Comment: @Idris Stack -yes